# Reading large files from NSInputstream is not working in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstream, nsinputstream, iphone-accessory

I am trying to read large Image file more than 300KB from NSInputStream. But i'm getting only upto 300KB. Other data are missing. Could you please help me if you know. i'm waiting for your valuable answer.
I mentioned my code below :
Call this readAllData method from NSStreamEventsHasBytesAvailable:

```
    - (void)readAllData {

    if (_readData == nil) {
    _readData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

    while ([[_session inputStream] hasBytesAvailable])
    {
    unsigned   int bytesRead = 0;
    bytesRead = [[_session inputStream] read:buf maxLength:EAD_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (bytesRead) {

        NSMutableString *_string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
        for (int i = 0; i < _readData.length; i++) {
            unsigned char _byte;
            [_readData getBytes:&_byte range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            if (_byte >= 32 && _byte < 127) {
                [_string appendFormat:@"%c", _byte];
            } else {
                [_string appendFormat:@"[%d]", _byte];
            }
        }

        [_readData appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:bytesRead];

    }

}

NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_readData.length];
UIAlertView *sesView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"readDatalength"
                                                  message:string
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK"  , nil];
[sesView show];
```

}

Comment: What is the size "EAD_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE" ?

Comment: 1024,and also i increased upto 5120. But no use

Answer (score 0):

When method `hasBytesAvailable` returns NO it doesn't always mean, that `NSInputStream` is empty. `NSInputStream` is at end only when its status is `NSStreamStatusAtEnd`. For example a stream which was been built from `NSURL` is asynchronous and it has no all bytes immediately after opening. If that is your case you should subscribe to `NSInputStream` declaring some class as `NSStreamDelegate`.